# SQL row_number() persistent

Tags: sql

I am using Microsoft SQL management studio 18.

If I have

| col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| A |
| B |
| B |

and I do "select *, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) col2 from [table]", I get

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

However after I did a cross apply function to it, the col2 values all become 1, and I know this is because row_number() function is dynamic. How do I make it non-dynamic and make the col2 values stay the same?

In my actual table, the col1 is the xml data, and I did

```
select * from mytable cross apply col1.nodes('//*:nodename[position()=sql:column("col2")]') as T(xml_node)
```

and this changed all the col2 values to 1.

Thank you

Comment: Ordering by the same partition is meaningless and non-deterministic. You have forgotton to show the cross apply query.

Comment: I am not trying to order this, it just requires order by statement. I can put like order by (select null) as well. I was wondering if there is a good alternative for the row_number() or if there is a way to make it persistent

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The above code snippet is product specific.

Comment: I fixed the post. lmk if you can help

Comment: Telling us you use Management Studio is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some; alarming from a mechanic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make it non-dynamic and make the col2 values stay the same?

[You can't.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se17_0zbZds&t=7s)

Without a **fully-deterministic** `ORDER BY`, a database server is free to order (and therefore number) the ambiguous rows any way it finds convenient. It can **and will** provide different orders for the *same query* from run to run based on things like index matching or piggybacking on reads done by another query already in progress, etc.

If you need the ordering to stay consistent, you **MUST** include enough information in the `ORDER BY` clause to uniquely rank each row. *There is no way around this.*

If the tables in the query do not include enough information to do this as part of the data, you're stuck.

Comment: it is unfortunate to know that I cannot make it non-dynamic, but thank you for answering and even attaching the link lol